# What was Laplace's argument?

Tags: thermodynamics, density, gas, molecules

In this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) article about Van der Waals gas equation there is a very nice derivation of the law in the conventional part. But in the last steps it is stated that pressure reduced on the walls of gas container is proportional to the square of gas' density which was found by Laplace. There is no reason given for it. As I am only a learner (and very curious), I won't be able to easily find out the reason.

So, my question is, *why is pressure reduced on the walls of a container is proportional to the square of the density of gas?*

Comment: [_Square_ of the density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation#Conventional_derivation).

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for finding out my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a derivation for myself. It hears like below.

Suppose, we have $n$ moles of gas with volume $V$ inside a container. The pressure is reduced because the $n$ moles of gas attracts surface particles towards the center of the container. So, the attractive potential energy on each mole of particles will be $U = a\frac {n}{V}$, where $a$ is a constant that depends on gas.

And for $n$ moles of gas particles the net potential is $\sum {U} = U\cdot n = a \frac {n^{2}}{V}$

Now we just need to divide the net potential with volume to get the energy density or the reduced pressure ($P'$) on walls.

So, $P' = a \frac {n^{2}}{V^{2}}$

$\therefore P' \propto {(\frac {n}{V})}^{2}$ [when gas is the same]

Now, it's easily understandable that the term $\frac {n}{V}$ is directly proportional to the density ($\rho$) of gas.

So, $\frac {n}{V} \propto   \rho$

$\therefore P' \propto \rho^{2}$

It's not actually the the derivation of Laplace's argument that Laplace used but it's clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

In the images below you see an two pages from van der Waal's thesis "[on the continuity of the gaseous and liquid states](https://www.lorentz.leidenuniv.nl/history/nobel_theses/sources/vanderWaals_1873.pdf)". It is written in Dutch which happens to be my native language. I'm not familiar with this work so this is my basic understanding of it. Here is a rough translation of the relevant section.

We will determine the force with which the surface of a material is drawn inwards. This force will depend on the type of material as well as the density. Imagine a small cylinder (literally: little pilar) which is large enough to include any particle which could exert an attractive force on the surface, i.e. long enough that a particle at the far end would exert negligible force on the surface. See the picture below.

If we now had a single molecule in this volume and we knew its place we could in principle determine the force it would exert on the surface. If the particle now were to move and go through every point in the volume then the problem becomes much easier; we would say the total force would be equal to the average of the force exerted by the particle as it visited every point in the volume (read: average the force over the volume). The same would hold true if we added a second particle and so on.

So the attraction will be proportional to the density. The same will hold for the particles in the surface layer. So we can conclude that the attraction will be proportional to the second power of density, or the inverse of the second power of volume.

Then there is a bit I don't fully understand but he concludes by saying that
$$\left(p+\frac{a}{v^2}\right)(v-b)=\sum\tfrac 1 3m V^2$$
where $p$ is the 'outward' pressure, $a$ the specific attraction, $v$ the volume, $b$ the molecular volume and $\sum\tfrac 1 3m V^2$ represents the temperature.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can I get a pdf format of these two pages from you? So that I can translate it into English?

Comment: @DebanjanBiswas The first link in my answer links to a PDF from which you can copy the text. You might be able to find an English version as well, but so far I haven't found one.

Comment: Oh, thank you for it.